# How is it decided whether a societal need should be met by using a public project or private enterprise?

Tags: public-goods

I know this is a large question, so I'm looking for a broad, general understanding only. **Are there any principles using which it may be decided to meet a societal need using a public project rather than private enterprise, in a free market economy?** What are all the factors that need to be considered? Moreover, is the government only supposed to provide public goods?

Comment: Is the development of the F-35 warplane by the private company Lockheed Martin a public project or a private enterprise?

Comment: "is the government only supposed to provide public goods" According to whom? A lot of politics is about this normative question. Please address the comments by editing your question, not by replying in comments.

Comment: That depends on your normative views and what decision criteria you apply. I think this question is too broad to be answered here. If you go for economic efficiency private enterprise is probably a better idea if competition is high and external costs are low. For public goods private enterprise tends to result in suboptimal outcomes in terms of efficiency.